# What are the advantages and disadvantages of Apply to Enclosed Items?

Tags: finder, command-line, permission, big-sur, folders

I had to use this on Users/John Doe/Library/Application Support/Firefox to allow it to create profiles properly (I'm on Firefox Developer Edition), on my admin account.

In general, what are the advantages and disadvantages of using **Apply to enclosed items....** via the Finder?

I read it's a potentially risky command, but only use it sparingly anyway via Finder.

Is this a fix for permissions problems / ACL's?

I'm on Big Sur, 11.4 on a 2020 MacBook Pro.

I am looking for advice on using this and its command-line equivalent and when is necessary to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The risk, honestly, is that if you make a mistake you percolate that mistake through that entire section of the file system. That can be tremendously time-consuming and headache-inducing to undo, assuming it can be undone at all. It isn't necessarily bad to use the Finder, you just need to be aware that the Finder's interface for permissions and ACLs is simplified for non-technical users. It doesn't give as much control as one would get in a terminal session or shell script, and makes some assumptions about what the user wants that are probably generally true, but not spelled out in detail.

It's best to think of a file system as the proverbial china shop. The more things you try to work with at once, the more havoc you will wreak if you slip up.

Comment: The biggest problem I have with the Finder's "Apply to enclosed items" is that it copies *all* permissions, not just the one change I want to make. Sometimes different items really should have different permissions, and setting everything the same in an attempt to fix one problem can easily cause other problems as a side effect. On something as small and specific as `/Users/John Doe/Library/Application Support/Firefox` it's probably fine, but on larger scales (like an entire home folder) it can cause serious problems.

Comment: @ Gordon Davisson: Thank you for the explanation!